# Hostinger email refuse to connect using Java Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, email, hosting

Hi im trying to use the email from Hostinger but having error in connection.

application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.hostinger.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=myMailFromHostinger
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Maven depedency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Code

```
    public void sendEmail(String email, String subject, String body) {
        JavaMailSender javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMailMessage.setFrom("myMailFromHostinger");
        simpleMailMessage.setTo(email);
        simpleMailMessage.setText(body);
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject(subject);

        javaMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);

    }
```

Error message

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Answer (score 0):

Give @Autowire annotation to javamailsender class

Comment: The error still same

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-boot-sending-email-via-smtp/  got to this link you will get